# Order by timestamp with range filter on different field Swift Firestore

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have asked this question before but not found a working solution yet.
What I want is to get a list of users within an age range and ordered by the 'createdAt' timestamp, but because of the 'birthday' range filter the first orderBy must be on 'birthday' field.

This is my query:

```
database.collection("users")
    .whereField("birthday", isGreaterThan: exploreSettings.upperAgeDate)
    .whereField("birthday", isLessThan: exploreSettings.lowerAgeDate)
    .whereField("isHidden", isEqualTo: false)
    .order(by: "birthday", descending: true)
    .order(by: "createdAt", descending: true)
    .limit(to: 8)
    .start(afterDocument: lastSnapshot)
    .getDocuments {...}
```

And this is what it will return

```
[
    ["name": "John", "age": 21, "createdAt": 2005],
    ["name": "Jane", "age": 22, "createdAt": 2003],
    ["name": "Adam", "age": 23, "createdAt": 2004],
    ["name": "Karl", "age": 24, "createdAt": 2001],
    ["name": "Mila", "age": 25, "createdAt": 2002],
]
```

And what I want it to return

```
[
    ["name": "Karl", "age": 24, "createdAt": 2001],
    ["name": "Mila", "age": 25, "createdAt": 2002],
    ["name": "Jane", "age": 22, "createdAt": 2003],
    ["name": "Adam", "age": 23, "createdAt": 2004],
    ["name": "John", "age": 21, "createdAt": 2005],
]
```

Some suggested that I somehow merged the birthday and created timestamp into a single field but I have know ideer how I should be able to do that

Comment: you want to sort your array using createdAt right.?

Comment: I want to populate the array sorted by createdAt @AbhirajsinhThakore

Comment: I have seen in your array inside, createdAt you do not have key value pair.? Is this you response.? or there is some error in printing that.? I can sort the array for you with "CreatedAt" key but if only  there is a key value pair in created at.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo in stack overflow. The arrays are just examples of what the query would get from the db and what et should get. @AbhirajsinhThakore

Comment: Added the Answer with edit and Output, please check that if it works for you.?

Comment: You can't directly query a child for a range of values and also sort by by a different child. What's the reason you don't query for your date range and then sort in code by createdAt?

Comment: Because I'm using pagination, so the next fetch may contain data that's newer than the first fetch. @Jay

Answer (score -1):

**Try Using this:**

```
      let arrResponse = [
        ["name": "John", "age": 21, "createdAt": 2005],
        ["name": "Jane", "age": 22, "createdAt": 2003],
        ["name": "Adam", "age": 23, "createdAt": 2004],
        ["name": "Karl", "age": 24, "createdAt": 2001],
        ["name": "Mila", "age": 25, "createdAt": 2002],
        ]


    let descriptor : NSSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "createdAt", ascending: true)

    let sortedResult = (arrResponse as NSArray).sortedArray(using: [descriptor])

    print(sortedResult)
```

The Output is like this:

[image]

Comment: Yes this will sort the array, but not what I was looking for. I need to get the newest users within an age range directly from the database with a firestore query

Comment: My approach is that fetch the data as it is and then sort like this so at any point you will be getting the latest data at top.

Comment: That would be a working solution, but because I'm using limit and pagination the next fetch may contain newer users as I scroll down.

Comment: May i know the reason why your query is not working.?

Comment: Because of the line ".order(by: "birthday", descending: true)" in the query.